# How to select 2 different columns from two different tables with COUNT and WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I really need your help on this, I have these queries where I want to select 2 columns of 2 different tables with count and where statement..

```
SELECT Error_Code as ISERR, 
       COUNT(Error_Code) as A 
FROM COMPIS 
WHERE test_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 06:00:00' AND '2020-01-10 18:00:00' 
  AND Error_Code <> ' ' 
GROUP BY Error_Code

SELECT error_code as SCERR, 
       COUNT(error_code) as B 
FROM COMPSER 
WHERE test_date_time BETWEEN '2020-01-01 06:00:00' AND '2020-01-10 18:00:00' 
  AND error_code <> ' ' 
GROUP BY error_code
```

I have tried these queries, but this only showed me null values.

```
SELECT A, a.ISERR, B, b.SCERR
FROM ( SELECT Error_Code as ISERR, 
              COUNT(Error_Code) as A 
       FROM COMPIS 
       WHERE test_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 06:00:00' AND '2020-01-10 18:00:00' 
         AND Error_Code <> ' ' 
       GROUP BY Error_Code ) a,
     ( SELECT error_code as SCERR, 
              COUNT(error_code) as B 
       FROM COMPSER 
       WHERE test_date_time BETWEEN '2020-01-01 06:00:00' AND '2020-01-10 18:00:00' 
         AND error_code <> ' ' 
       GROUP BY error_code ) b
```

OUTPUT was:

```
A    | ISERR | B   | SCERR
-----+-------+-----+------
null   null   null   null
```

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to come here SHOUTING when asking for free help to solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: okay. BTW. I am impressed that you think/heard that I am SHOUTING LOL

Comment: Like everywhere else on the internet, typing in ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING. Be polite. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT error_code, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN table='A' THEN cnt END) cnt_A, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN table='B' THEN cnt END) cnt_B
FROM ( SELECT Error_Code as ISERR, 
              COUNT(Error_Code) as cnt,
              `A` as table 
       FROM COMPIS 
       WHERE test_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 06:00:00' AND '2020-01-10 18:00:00' 
         AND Error_Code <> ' ' 
       GROUP BY Error_Code
     UNION ALL
       SELECT error_code, 
              COUNT(error_code),
              'B'
       FROM COMPSER 
       WHERE test_date_time BETWEEN '2020-01-01 06:00:00' AND '2020-01-10 18:00:00' 
         AND error_code <> ' ' 
       GROUP BY error_code ) total
GROUP BY error_code
```

If you need NULL instead of zeros use MAX instead SUM.